# How to do this two complex integrals?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, contour-integration

The first integral reads:

$$
f(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}k_x \, \mathrm{d}k_y \, \mathrm{d}k_z \, \frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}}{(k_0-\alpha k_z)^2-k^2+i(k_0-\alpha k_z)\eta}
$$

the second integral is very similar, except the infinitesimal parts:
$$
f(\vec{r})=\iiint_{-\infty}^\infty \mathrm{d}k_x \, \mathrm{d}k_y \, \mathrm{d}k_z \, \frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}}{(k_0-\alpha k_z)^2-k^2+i\eta}
$$

where $\alpha>1$, $k_0>0$ is finite positive number, $\eta = 0^+$ is the infinitesimal positive number. $\vec{k}=(k_x,k_y,k_z), \vec{r}=(x,y,z), k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2+k_z^2}$.

**As a hint**, the integral for $\alpha=0$ can be done as following:

\begin{align}
&\int\mathrm{d}^3k \frac{e^{i\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}}}{k_0^2-k^2+i\eta} \quad\text{--- making $\vec{r}$ as $z$ axis for $\vec{k}$ } \\
=& 2\pi\int_{-1}^1\mathrm{d}\xi\int_0^\infty \mathrm{d}k k^2\frac{e^{ikr\xi}}{k_0^2-k^2+i\eta}\quad\text{--- integral over $\phi_k$, and let $\xi=\cos\theta_k$}\\
=&-\frac{2\pi}{i r} \int_0^\infty \frac{k\,\mathrm{d}k}{k^2-(k_0^2+i\eta)}(e^{ikr}-e^{-ikr})\\
=&-\frac{2\pi}{i r}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{k\,\mathrm{d}k}{k^2-(k_0^2+i\eta)}e^{ikr} \quad\text{--- use the upper semicircle as contour.} \\
=&-(2\pi)^2\frac{e^{ik_0r}}{2r}
\end{align}

*It seems that the first integral is zero as pointed by @Fabian. As for the second integral, @Felix Martin makes a variable substitution and integrate out one dimension, it seems that it's hard to proceed and get an analytical form.*

**Therefore, is it possible to get the asymptotic form of the second integral when $r\to\infty$? (i.e. keep only $1/r$ part, ignore $1/r^2$ etc.)**

Comment: Your final result does not seem to be correct; it is missing a factor $e^{i k_0 r}$.

Comment: @Fabian You are right, I will add it...

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}}} & =
\iiint\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dd k_{x}\,\dd k_{y}\,\dd k_{z}\,{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} \over
\pars{k_{0} - \alpha k_{x}}^{\, 2} - k^{2} + \ic\eta}
\\[5mm] & =
\iiint\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} \over
\alpha^{2}\pars{k_{0}/\alpha - k_{x}}^{\, 2} - k^{2} + \ic\eta}
\,\dd k_{x}\,\dd k_{y}\,\dd k_{z}
\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}
Now, I make the substitution
$\ds{\pars{k_{x} - {k_{0} \over \alpha}} \mapsto k_{x}}$ in \eqref{1}:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}}} & =
\iiint\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\pars{k_{x}\ +\ k_{0}\,/\alpha}x}\
\expo{\ic k_{y}\,y\ +\ \ic k_{z}\,z} \over
\alpha^{2}k_{x}^{\, 2} - \pars{k_{x} + k_{0}/\alpha}^{2} - k_{y}^{2} - k_{z}^{2} + \ic\eta}\,\dd k_{x}\,\dd k_{y}\,\dd k_{z}
\\[5mm] & =
\exp\pars{{k_{0} \over \alpha}\,x\,\ic}\iiint\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\vec{k}\cdot\vec{r}} \over
\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}k_{x}^{2} -2k_{0}k_{x}/\alpha- k_{y}^{2} - k_{z}^{2} - k_{0}^{2}/\alpha^{2} + \ic\eta}
\,\dd k_{x}\,\dd k_{y}\,\dd k_{z}
\end{align}

---

Then,
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}}} & =
\exp\pars{{k_{0} \over \alpha}\,x\,\ic}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\expo{\ic k_{x}\,x}
{\expo{\ic\rho\bracks{y\cos\pars{\theta} + z\sin\pars{\theta}}}} \over
\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}k_{x}^{2} -2k_{0}k_{x}/\alpha - \rho^{2} - k_{0}^{2}/\alpha^{2} + \ic\eta}\,\,\,\,\,\dd\theta\,\dd\rho\,\dd k_{x}
\end{align}
The $\ds{\theta}$-integral can be expressed in terms of the $\ds{\,\mathrm{J}_{0}}$ *Bessel Function*:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\mrm{f}\pars{\vec{r}}} & =
2\pi\exp\pars{{k_{0} \over \alpha}\,x\,\ic}
\int_{0}^{\infty}\rho\,\mrm{J}_{0}\pars{\root{y^{2} + z^{2}}\rho}\times
\\&
\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k_{x}\,x}
\over \pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}k_{x}^{2} -2k_{0}k_{x}/\alpha - \rho^{2} - k_{0}^{2}/\alpha^{2} + \ic\eta}\,\,\,\,\,\dd k_{x}}
_{\ds{\mc{F}_{1}\pars{\rho} + \mc{F}_{2}\pars{\rho}}}\,\dd\rho
\end{align}

---

I assume $\ds{\alpha > 0}$ and $\ds{\eta = 0^{+}}$ ( for the purpose of the example ):
\begin{align}
\mc{F}_{1}\pars{\rho} & =
\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic k_{x}\,x}
\over \pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}k_{x}^{2} -2k_{0}k_{x}/\alpha - \rho^{2} - k_{0}^{2}/\alpha^{2}}\,\dd k_{x}
\\[5mm]
\mc{F}_{2}\pars{\rho} & =
-\ic\pi
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k_{x}\,x}
\delta\pars{\bracks{\alpha^{2} - 1}k_{x}^{2} -2k_{0}k_{x}/\alpha - \rho^{2} - k_{0}^{2}/\alpha^{2}}\,\dd k_{x}
\end{align}
The $\ds{\delta}$-argument vanishes out when $\ds{k_{x}}$ takes the values
$\ds{k_{x\pm}\pars{\rho} =
{k_{0} \pm \alpha\root{\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}\rho^{2} + k_{0}^{2}} \over \alpha\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}}}$.
\begin{align}
\mc{F}_{2}\pars{\rho} & =
-\ic\,{\pi \over \alpha^{2} - 1}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k_{x}x}
\delta\pars{\bracks{k_{x} - k_{x+}\pars{\rho}}
\bracks{k_{x} - k_{x-}\pars{\rho}}}\,\dd k_{x}
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\,{\pi \over \alpha^{2} - 1}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\expo{\ic k_{x}x}\,
{\delta\pars{k_{x} - k_{x+}\pars{\rho}} +
{\delta\pars{k_{x} - k_{x-}\pars{\rho}}} \over
\verts{2k_{x} - k_{x+}\pars{\rho} -  k_{x-}\pars{\rho}}}\,\dd k_{x}
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\,{\pi \over \root{\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}\rho^{2} + k_{0}^{2}}}
\bracks{\exp\pars{\ic k_{x+}\pars{\rho}x} + \exp\pars{\ic k_{x-}\pars{\rho}x}}
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\,{2\pi \over \root{\pars{\alpha^{2} - 1}\rho^{2} + k_{0}^{2}}}\,
\exp\pars{{k_{0} \over \alpha\bracks{\alpha^{2} - 1}}\,x\ic}
\cos\pars{{\root{\bracks{\alpha^{2} - 1}\rho^{2} + k_{0}^{2}} \over
\alpha^{2} - 1}\,x\ic}
\end{align}

Comment: Thanks for the answer! However I've edit a lit bit of the integrand, the infinite small $\eta$ has a coefficients in front. I'll check if this affects your current derivation(if does, I will edit it)...

Comment: I'm sorry, but in your second line you dropped a constant.

Comment: I think that dropping the factor before $\eta$, you have changed the value of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Your integral is zero for $\alpha>1$. For that you only have to look at the integral over $k_z$. As the integral decays fast enough, it is amenable to be treated by the method of residues. Let us take a look at the denominator ($\rho^2 = k_x^2 + k_y^2$)

$$D = (k_0 - \alpha k_z)^2 - \rho^2 -k_z^2 + i (k_0 -\alpha k_z) \eta.$$

The roots of this quadratic polynomial (for $k_z$) are in the complex plane situated at ($\beta =\alpha^2 -1 > 1$)
$$ k_{3\pm} = \frac{1}{\beta} \left( k_0 \alpha \pm \sqrt{k_0^2 +\beta \rho^2}\right) + i \tilde\eta_\pm.$$

The imaginary parts $\tilde \eta$ have to be only evaluated to first order in $\eta$, we obtain
$$ \tilde \eta_\pm = \frac{\eta}{2 \beta} \left( \alpha \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 + \beta \rho^2 /k_0^2}} \right). \tag{1}$$

Now observe that $\sqrt{1 + \beta \rho^2 /k_0^2}>1$ such that the term in the bracket of (1) is always positive ($\alpha>1$). Thus, we have that $\tilde \eta_\pm>0$ (both poles are above the real axis). Closing the contour below the real axis, we immediately obtain that your integral vanishes.

Comment: Your observation is very acute! It seems has no problem.

Comment: Can I ask again if the infinitesimal part is just $i\eta$? I'll clarify your answer to this situation.